# Trouble displaying an Image on my Panel

Tags: c#, image, panel, system.drawing

I'm trying to draw images for a game on to a Panel in C#. I get no images being drawn and I can't figure out why this method is never called:

> private void playerPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)

Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace FlightOfTheNavigator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        // Load Sprites
        public Bitmap playerShip = new Bitmap(FlightOfTheNavigator.Properties.Resources.testship);

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();        
            SetupGame();
        }

        public void SetupGame()
        {
            // Setup Console
            txtConsole.Text = "Loading Ship Bios v3.4.12c ..." + 
                               Environment.NewLine + 
                               "Console Ready" + 
                               Environment.NewLine + 
                               "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" + 
                               Environment.NewLine +
                               Environment.NewLine;

            // Setup Basic Weapons
            listWeapons.Items.Add("Pulse Lazers");
            listWeapons.Items.Add("Cluster Missiles");

            // Set Shield Perecentage
            txtShields.Text = "0%";
        }

        private void trackShield_Scroll(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtShields.Text = "" + trackShield.Value + "%";
        }

        private void playerPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics g = playerPanel.CreateGraphics();
            g.DrawImage(playerShip, 0, 0,100,100);
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Invalidate the panel. This will lead to a call of 'playerPanel_Paint'
            playerPanel.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure the `Paint` event of the panel is attached to `playerPanel_Paint`.

Comment: @Haden693: That was definately different problem.

Comment: Thanks Unicorn that solved the problem. The auto generated code wasn't linking the panel to the event. This was the fix;
"this.playerPanel.Paint += new System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventHandler(this.playerPanel_Paint);".

Comment: In newer C# versions (8 years or younger) you could even write `this.playerPanel.Paint += playerPanel_Paint;`

Comment: So let's make it an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the `Paint` event of the panel is attached to `playerPanel_Paint` method.

Open the Desinger, select the panel (`playerPanel`), press <kbd>F4</kbd> to bring up the Properties window, then click the lightning bolt above the Properties window to show the events. Check the `Paint` event there. If it is empty, open the drop-down and select `playerPanel_Paint` method.

You can also do it in code. Put this into the form's constructor after `InitializeComponent()`:

```
this.playerPanel.Paint += PaintEventHandler(playerPanel_Paint);
```